# Can you or companions be revived more than once?

Tags: ashen

I played most of Ashen with a companion, and sometimes they would revive me after some particularly hair-raising maneuvers or I would revive them. But sometimes one of us would just die instantly even if the other was still alive and kicking. Is there a limit to revivals, such as only once between ritual stones?